# VS Code with PowerShell 7 issue

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, powershell-core

**Context**

I've recently installed PowerShell 7 (7.0.0, Core), which is working on my Windows 10 system. (so far I had used PowerShell 5.x) I am also using VS Code 1.44.1 (user setup). I am using PowerShell extension 2020.3.0 (PowerShell Language Support for Visual Studio Code).

The extension worked seamlessly with PowerShell 5.x. It now tries to load PowerShell 7 but fails. It works again if I uninstall PowerShell 7.

**Question**

How to make VS Code and PowerShell Language Support for Visual Studio Code (2020.3.0) work with PowerShell 7?

**What I've tried so far?**

I've uninstalled and installed everything (I mean: The extension itself, the whole VS Code, PowerShell 7. in every combinations and order. The result is the same. VSCode with the extension and PowerShell 7 fails to load.

**Diagnostics**

Error message when the extension tried to load the PowerShell terminal:

> The terminal process command 'C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command 'Import-Module 'c:\Users\gabor.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.powershell-2020.3.0\modules\PowerShellEditorServices\PowerShellEditorServices.psd1'; Start-EditorServices -HostName 'Visual Studio Code Host' -HostProfileId 'Microsoft.VSCode' -HostVersion '2020.3.0' -AdditionalModules @('PowerShellEditorServices.VSCode') -BundledModulesPath 'c:\Users\gabor.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.powershell-2020.3.0\modules' -EnableConsoleRepl -LogLevel 'Normal' -LogPath 'c:\Users\gabor.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.powershell-2020.3.0\logs\1586928317-0235b7d4-82ec-4688-a730-145f439135671586928305363\EditorServices.log' -SessionDetailsPath 'c:\Users\gabor.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.powershell-2020.3.0\sessions\PSES-VSCode-9928-283855' -FeatureFlags @() '' failed to launch (exit code: {2})

The log: (Sorry for the double newlines in the blockquote... I do not know how to get rid of them)

> 2020. 4. 15. 7:25:17 [NORMAL] - Visual Studio Code v1.44.1 64-bit
> 2021. 4. 15. 7:25:17 [NORMAL] - PowerShell Extension v2020.3.0
> 2022. 4. 15. 7:25:17 [NORMAL] - Operating System: Windows 64-bit
> 2023. 4. 15. 7:25:17 [NORMAL] - Language server starting --
> 2024. 4. 15. 7:25:17 [NORMAL] -     PowerShell executable: C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe
> 2025. 4. 15. 7:25:17 [NORMAL] -     PowerShell args: -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command Import-Module 'c:\Users\gabor.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.powershell-2020.3.0\modules\PowerShellEditorServices\PowerShellEditorServices.psd1'; Start-EditorServices -HostName 'Visual Studio Code Host' -HostProfileId 'Microsoft.VSCode' -HostVersion '2020.3.0' -AdditionalModules @('PowerShellEditorServices.VSCode') -BundledModulesPath 'c:\Users\gabor.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.powershell-2020.3.0\modules' -EnableConsoleRepl -LogLevel 'Normal' -LogPath 'c:\Users\gabor.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.powershell-2020.3.0\logs\1586928317-0235b7d4-82ec-4688-a730-145f439135671586928305363\EditorServices.log' -SessionDetailsPath 'c:\Users\gabor.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.powershell-2020.3.0\sessions\PSES-VSCode-9928-283855' -FeatureFlags @()
> 2026. 4. 15. 7:25:17 [NORMAL] -     PowerShell Editor Services args: Import-Module 'c:\Users\gabor.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.powershell-2020.3.0\modules\PowerShellEditorServices\PowerShellEditorServices.psd1'; Start-EditorServices -HostName 'Visual Studio Code Host' -HostProfileId 'Microsoft.VSCode' -HostVersion '2020.3.0' -AdditionalModules @('PowerShellEditorServices.VSCode') -BundledModulesPath 'c:\Users\gabor.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.powershell-2020.3.0\modules' -EnableConsoleRepl -LogLevel 'Normal' -LogPath 'c:\Users\gabor.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.powershell-2020.3.0\logs\1586928317-0235b7d4-82ec-4688-a730-145f439135671586928305363\EditorServices.log' -SessionDetailsPath 'c:\Users\gabor.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.powershell-2020.3.0\sessions\PSES-VSCode-9928-283855' -FeatureFlags @()
> 2027. 4. 15. 7:25:17 [NORMAL] - pwsh.exe started.
> 2028. 4. 15. 7:25:17 [NORMAL] - Waiting for session file
> 2029. 4. 15. 7:27:18 [NORMAL] - Error occurred retrieving session file
> 2030. 4. 15. 7:27:18 [NORMAL] - Language server startup failed.
> 2031. 4. 15. 7:27:18 [ERROR] - The language service could not be started:
> 2032. 4. 15. 7:27:18 [ERROR] - Timed out waiting for session file to appear.

Comment: You might find better support for this extension at their repository: https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell

Comment: Maybe this [GH issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/2544) helps.

Comment: Are you running the Avecto/BeyondTrust privilege management stuff? There seems to be a conflict there where the extension server startup is blocked by Avecto.

Comment: @EdCallahan, no I am not running any 3rd party stuff